# Docker only updates image when the /var/lib/docker folder is deleted

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have an Extjs project with PHP in the backend and using docker 23.0.4, whenever I push a new image to my dockerhub and pull it into my server the changes made in the new image just doesn't take place.

I've tried several times to clear cache, system / image prune, delete the imagem then pulling it again (no layer is shown to be already existent during the pull and the newer image still doesn't seem to run, the older codes remains). It is not a docker tagging problem.

The only way I could get it to work is deleting the /var/lib/docker folder, but I know this should not be adopted as practice for everytime I need to pull a new version of my system, so I'm looking forward any possible cause of this problem and a way to solve it.
This is my very first question here, if any further info is needed please let me know.
Thank y'all in advance!